# What are the conjugacy classes in $A_5$?

Tags: group-theory, definition, symmetric-groups

I'm new to group-theory and to the Alternating groups. In my book I got asked the following questions:

> What are the conjugacy classes in $A_5$?

Where should I start? What does it mean, "conjugacy"?

Comment: Which book are you using? Please [edit] the question to include the details.

Comment: For any $\sigma\in A_5$, the conjugacy map $c_\sigma:A_5\to A_5$ is defined by $c_\sigma(\tau)=\sigma^{-1}\tau\sigma$ for each $\tau\in A_5$.

Comment: It's a homomorphism. Find its kernel.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class

Comment: I think you probably need to do some work on basic group theory concepts before trying to apply them.

Comment: Start by looking up the word "conjugacy" in the text. How were you planning on solving the problem if you don't know what it means?

Answer (score 0):

The conjugacy class $[\tau]_{A_5}$ of $\tau\in A_5$ is defined by $$[\tau]_{A_5}:=\{c_\sigma(\tau)\mid \sigma\in A_5\},$$ where $$\begin{align} c_\sigma: A_5 &\to A_5, \\ \pi &\mapsto \sigma^{-1}\pi\sigma\end{align}$$ is the conjugacy map.